# Bundle value is null on samsung M31 devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, samsung-mobile

Pending intent is passing null bundle values to activity when attached to a notification click.

This is happening only in the recently launched Samsung M31 devices and Samsung Galaxy G6 10. It is working fine in all other devices.

Code ->

```
        val intent =  Intent(context, CollabcardDetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("unique_id", notificationId)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Here, notificationId is a unique non zero integer.
Also, the function getRouteIntent() is working fine as the intent is starting the activity, only the bundle is always null on the mentioned devices.

Comment: Did you tried setting a `requestCode` in your `PendinIntent` object? `requestCode` must not be zero

Comment: Please add your code in the question

Comment: @null_override Added the code. Please check.

Comment: @artenson.art98 Yes I have set a request code and it is non zero positive integer.

Comment: @gaurav try setting the requestCode value above 1000

Comment: Are there any other "extras" in the `Intent`?

Comment: @DavidWasser No there are no other extras. I used simple primitive data types to pass data but its now working at all.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code in `getRouteIntent()`. Without looking at the code we cannot help you.